# how to create the debug.keystore registration ( android )

Tags: android, debugging, keystore

hi i trying to upload app to Samsung app store and every time i upload the app they send to me this message :

```
Result : Pr-Review rejected(API Fail)
Failure Details: This app using debug key store:C N=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
```

and i deleted the debug.key store from `"C:\Users\android\debug.key store"` 
and reinstalling the eclipse with the last update and there is the same problem every time i trying to upload any apk to Samsung store its rejected

so is any one know how to solve this problem or what is this problem meaning ?

Comment: the problem is that you can't publish an application signed with the debug key, first you have to make your own and use it to sign the app, then upload the apk

Answer (score 1):

You cannot publish your apps using a debug key. In your IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio) go to `Build > Generate Signed APK` and create a keystore.